# django.request: Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.)

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn, amazon-elb

I am developing a web application using AWS, and Django Rest Framework.(Django:v1.8, DRF:v3)
I have kept getting `django.request: Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.)` for POST multipart form request.

I am using AWS ELB(Elastic load balancer), NGINX on my ec2(in autoscailing group) and Gunicorn.

AWS ELB listener setting is like below(HTTPS only):

[elb https only listener setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8Ter.jpg)

NGINX setting is like below:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    include         /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type    application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    upstream my_server {
        server localhost:8000;
    }

    server {

        listen       80;
        server_name  <server name>;
        access_log   /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.access.log;
        error_log    /etc/nginx/log/local-wc.error.log;
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        location /api/v1 {
            proxy_pass          http://my_server/api/v1;
            proxy_redirect      off;
            proxy_set_header    Host            $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol $scheme;
        }
    }
}
```

`<server name>` is the CNAME which point to elb DNS name.

In other words, `<server name>` => xxxx-123456789.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com (A Record).
Every API call is made by `https://<server name>/api/v1/*`

Finally Gunicorn is running by:
`gunicorn my_django_app.wsgi:application -w 1 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -t 300 --max-requests=100`

and Django Setting is:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
```

View function is like below(with CSRF exempt):

```
class UserViewSet(CsrfExemptMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin,
              mixins.ListModelMixin,
              mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
              mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
              viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    # already tried @csrf_exempt
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser, )
        .........
```

Problem again:

When I send

```
curl -i -k -X POST -H "Accept: application/json" \
    -F "email=myemail@email.com" \
    -F "profile_img=@profile.jpg" \
    https://<server name>/api/v1/users/
```

and in my Django log:

```
[WARNING] django.request: Forbidden (Referer checking failed - no Referer.): /api/v1/users/
```

It worked with POST on HTTP or GET method on HTTPS.

I wonder whether ELB configuration is wrong or Nginx Configuration is wrong with referer...
I would appreciate if some one help me to solve this problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think DRF ignores csrf_exempt decorator and I am not sure where the CsrfExemptMixin is defined. The easiest thing you can do is add `Referrer: yourhost` to your curl headers.

Comment: what about mobile apps like one built in React Native?